# How to read a return from a class - android

Tags: android, class, methods, return, return-type

I have doing a file from the server, 
and my idea is to pass the filesizedownloaded to a class and on my progressbar class get value to update the progress bar;
I have a function that passes a value to a class

this is how i try to pass the value

> new updateValue(fileSizeDownloaded);

value gets stored here
       public class updateValue{
            private long v_value;

```
        public updateValue(long value) {
            v_value = value;
        }

        public long getV_value() { return v_value; };
    }
```

and from a different class I'm trying to get the value of getV_value but I keep getting an error; update(long) in update cannot be applied to 0

How can i get the value stored :/ all this is on mainactivity.java

```
updateValue value = new updateValue();
value.getV_value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a new class and extend Application

```
public class yourcalss extends Application {
      public long getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(long value_e) {
            value = value_e;
        }
}
```

This is how you save the value

```
final yourcalss value = (yourcalss ) getApplicationContext();
value.setValue(fileSizeDownloaded);
```

and this is how you can access the value

```
final yourcalss val = (yourcalss ) getApplicationContext();
final Long v = val.getValue();
```

and manifiest

```
<application android:name="yourcalss
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the initial value when creating an instance of `updateValue`. Pass a value like this

```
long val = 1000; //can be any long value
updateValue value = new updateValue(val);
value.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks bro,but the value is already there, with updateValue value i'm only trying to acces the value stored int  public class updateValue

Comment: I have updated my question with a little more details, sorry

Comment: @CarlosCastro I see, in that case, I think the problem is that you're creating a new instance of the class `updateValue` not the same class you created at first. So better use a `ViewModel` class. More on that here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel